# Google Earth Engine - Delayed data in Google Data Catalog

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to run an experiment to see if I can get the latest data from a data source in the GEE Data catalog. On further inspection the latest data is not available on GEE yet, but it is available at the source.

If the data is not yet available in the data catalog, does that mean I can't access the latest data in GEE until Google updates the data source?

Please see the dataset link below from GEE: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MCD15A3H

Original data source: https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD15A3H.061/2024.01.17/

The above link shows that the latest data is available.

Comment: These links are to two different datasets (15A2H vs 15A3H).

Comment: Hi Simon, sorry about that. 

Here is the updated link : https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD15A3H.061/

Comment: That's something usual, GEE data catalog ingests data from sources. If the delay between the data source and the GEE data catalog is too extensive, raise this concern to GEE users forum. Here, we don't have the tools to fix this issue

Comment: Thanks @aldo_tapia. I just wanted to see if there might be a different solution.

I also got a response back from Google as well.

If the most recent data has not yet been added to the Google Earth Engine (GEE) Data Catalog, it is unfortunately not possible to access it through GEE until Google updates the catalog with this new data.
However, since you have access to the original source, you could opt to manually download the data files, though this process requires more effort in your part.

Comment: I work with MCD15A2H (and other modis products) in a project (streamflow forecasting with ML) and we need the product as soon as possible, so GEE is not an option for us. I download the products earthaccess library, which use earthdata CMR api

Answer (score 0):

The latest asset MCD15A3H.061/2024.01.17/ is being ingested right now. We only downloaded the files for it today even though they were produced two days ago - I agree this is a little strange. Will look.